# "was lost", "had lost", "had been lost". Which one suits best this context and how do they differ in conveying meaning?

Tags: past-tense, sentence-choice

Which one suits best? What are the differences? How do they differ in conveying meaning?

Last month, when I was walking in the street, I faced a little girl who ...

> 1. had been lost in the city.

> 2. had lost in the city.

> 3. was lost in the city.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only 3 is possible.  This is because you want the adjective "lost" to describe the girl.  You don't want the verb "to lose something", since this would imply that someone lost the girl.

The first must be a passive voice, it means someone lost the girl, probably deliberately, that is she was abandoned. It might also mean that she had experienced being lost, but wasn't lost when you met her.  Neither interpretation seems likely, so I'd assume that this was just a mistake.

The second is incorrect, since "lose" requires an object.

The third is acceptable since you can understand "lost" to be an adjective.  (formally it is ambiguous, but since the adjective makes more sense, you wouldn't parse this as a passive voice sentence)

Comment: The answer of Seowjooheng Singapore contradicts your answer. I'm confused. Seowjooheng Singapore says #1 can also be correct. Could you please elaborate more on this?

Comment: 1. can be correct grammatically, but doesn't mean the same as 3.  The meaning of 1. is odd and I don't think you mean "I met a girl who had experienced being lost at some time in the past".

Comment: But Seowjooheng is allowed to disagree with me!  Your use of "faced" is very odd too.  I've changed it to "met" since I'm assuming that your use of the verb "faced" is just a mistake.

Comment: I used "faced" because I wanted to emphasis that I have conceived the situation as a challenging and problematic condition. You may meet a little girl in the street and then walk away. It is different from when you see a lost little girl and you want to help her. Is "faced" still odd in this case?

Answer (score 1):

> Last month, when I was walking in the street, I **faced** a little girl who ...

> [1] had been lost in the city.
> [2] had lost in the city.
> [3] was lost in the city.

#2 is ungrammatical.

If the little girl was lost for just a short while, both #1 and #3 are possible, but I would use #3 as we should not use the perfect unnecessarily.

If the little girl had been lost for a much longer period, say, for days, #1 would be appropriate.  *faced* in your question gives a sense that the girl had been lost for quite a long time.  I would hence use #1.

Comment: The answer of James K contradicts your answer. 
I'm confused. James K says "Only 3 is possible." and "The first must be a passive voice, it means someone lost the girl, probably deliberately, that is she was abandoned." Could you please elaborate more on this?

Comment: Hi, @alireza, there was nothing stating the contrary; hence, I would not want to rule out the possibilities stated.

Comment: #1 is not truly idiomatic "as is". Semantically speaking, it's fragmentary -- missing some required information.  If the intended meaning  is "had become lost", that is, something like "had become separated from her parents and had been wandering the streets", it needs some sort of time phrase  to justify the use of the past perfect. "...I encountered a little girl who had been lost *for two days*".